# Creating Ubuntu bootable disk in Windows using my phone

Tags: usb

I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop but because I have a complete shortage of writable CDs and DVDs, I wan't to create a bootable USB stick (on Windows).

However, the only USB stick I currently have lying around is my HTC phone (HTC Touch HD with 8Gb memory). I was following the [Ubuntu guide to create a bootable usb stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) with [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/#button), however in the last step it shows me that it wants to do more than just copying the `.iso` file to the USB drive:

[image]

My question: can I safely proceed without wiping the current OS off my phone (Windows Mobile 6.1) and use it to install Ubuntu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you cannot safely proceed. While HTC phones usually only mount the SD card, rather than their own storage, you will definitely format whatever storage device you currently have mounted. That means, even if you don't remove the OS itself, you will lose data - and most likely data you wouldn't want to lose.
I recommend getting an actual USB drive (4GB stick minimum), which should be available at really low pricing nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so.

You need to have a FAT32 partition to make a bootable USB Stick, so unless you can find a way to make a FAT32 partition on your phone, I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

if your phone is rooted and you have enough storage you may this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid&hl=pl&gl=US but it will make PHONE, not sd card as bootable device. if your not rooted/not have enough storage - you are out of luck, then sorry.